# Returning exact change in SWIFT

Tags: swift, class, methods

I'm struggling with making sense of how to return the changeDue for my assignment. Trying to revise my incorrect code for class in prep for intro to programming final.
all I am trying to do is: create a method called quarters().  When I pass any double value (ChangeDue) into the method, I want to know precisely how many quarters there are as well as the partial quarter change returned.

**Original code:**

```swift
func getChange(Quarters: Double) -> Double {
    var Change = Quarters
    return Change;
}

var Quarters = 0.72;
var ChangeDue = getChange(Quarters / .25);

print(ChangeDue)
```

**Slightly revised code which I seem to have made worse:**

```swift
class changeDue {

    var = quarters(.72)

    func changeDue(Quarters: Double) {
        var Change = Quarters
        changeDue = changeDue - (quarters*.25)
    }

    var ChangeDue = getChange(int / .25);
    print(changeDue)
}
```

notes/Feedback:
create a method called quarters().  When I pass any double value (ChangeDue) into the method, I want to know precisely how many quarters there are as well as the partial quarter change returned.

Create a class level variable, changeDue.  This is where you will set your test input e.g. .78, 2.15.

In your method, calculate the number of quarters as the integer of changeDue/.25
Print the number of quarters.
Now you need the revised change after quarters are removed.  changeDue=changeDue - (quarters*.25)

quarters = the integer of changedue/.25
changeDue is now = to the previous changeDue - (quarters times .25)

quarters(.72)
the integer of .72/.25 = 2
changedue=.72-(2 x .25)     or  .72 - .50 =.12
Print changeDue.

Any help would be appreciated. I've been working on this for longer than I want to admit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint 1:** Do not work with Double or fractional amounts. Turn dollars into pennies by multiplying everything by 100 before you start. Now you can do everything with integer arithmetic. After you get the answer, you can always divide by 100 to turn it back into dollars, if desired.

**Hint 2:** Do you know about the `%` operator? It tells you the remainder after a division.

I don't want to write your code for you (it's you who are being tested, not me, after all), but I'll just demonstrate with a different example:

`51 / 7` is `7`, because integer division throws away the remainder.

Sure, 7x7 is 49, with something left over. But what?

Answer: `51 % 7` is `2`. Do you see?